# Fiddler vs Firebug

Tags: firebug, fiddler

Hopefully this is not a duplicate question as most of the answer I see on same subject are quite old (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300041/fiddler-vs-firefox-w-firebug)) and lot of changed since then. I wonder what are the features you prefer to use in Fiddler vs Firebug with their latest releases available? Or to be more specific, what things that Fiddler do and cannot be done via Firebug? Also the vice versa?

Comment: Why close? If its due to duplicate, can you post a link where I can find answer based on relatively new versions of Fiddler vs Firebug?

Comment: It's a bit of a subjective question: `what are the features you prefer` - this makes it hard to answer the question objectively, and solicites debate. These type of questions are disouraged on StackOverflow. Please review the [faq] for more information.

Comment: OK, reworded the question based on faq

Comment: Fiddler allows modification of in-flight HTTP/HTTPS requests, changing what the browser and server see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fiddler and Firebug are two different tools that I use to solve two different problems.

Firebug is primarily used to Inspect / Tweak the DOM, script debugging, and basic network information. It primarily deals with things *inside the browser*.

Some things you would use Firebug for is tweaking CSS styles, trying to figure out where some style is coming from, etc. It can also be used for breakpoints in JavaScript, and basic request / response information such as content, headers, timing, etc.

Fiddler goes much further underneath of it. Fiddler is useful for inspecting network / protocol level information that the browser is doing, as well has a lot of analysis helpers. I typically use this when I am trying to diagnose compression issues, see network traffic, very fine grained details for timing, or making your own requests to the server, which I do when I am tinkering with SOAP / Web Services.